# How to get AVCaptureDevice videoZoomFactor in x-times?

Tags: ios, swift4, avcapturedevice

I have implement following code to get zoom factor which is working fine

```
var maxZoomScale = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
var beginZoomScale               = CGFloat(1.0)
var zoomScale                    = CGFloat(1.0)

fileprivate func zoomGesture(pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        guard pinchToZoom == true && self.currentCamera == .rear else {
            //ignore pinch
            return
        }
        do {
            let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.devices().first
            try captureDevice?.lockForConfiguration()

            zoomScale = min(maxZoomScale, max(1.0, min(beginZoomScale * pinch.scale,  captureDevice!.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor)))

            captureDevice?.videoZoomFactor = zoomScale

            // Call Delegate function with current zoom scale
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("zoomScale : \(self.zoomScale)")
                self.cameraDelegate?.swiftyCam(self, didChangeZoomLevel: self.zoomScale)
            }

            captureDevice?.unlockForConfiguration()

        } catch {
            print("Error locking configuration")
        }
    }
```

Now that `var zoomScale` gives me zoom factor like 1.011 to its max zoom factor which is right now i'm getting up to 1.98.
**I need that as X-time** like 1x,2x,3x ....
So how can i get that?